# Displaying and Referencing a json_encode in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am not sure what the best method to display this is. I am creating an activity log for my website that is adaptable between different controllers. Here is my encode code:

```
$properties = [
    'last_name' => $request->last_name,
    'first_name' => $request->first_name,
    'dob' => $request->dob,
    'unique_id' => $unique_id,
    'doctor_id' => $doctor->id
];
$log->properties = json_encode($properties);
```

However, properties on a different controller might have fields like `revenue`, `address`, etc, etc.

On the show page of my activity log controller, right now I am using `{{$log->properties}}` to display the object. It returns something like this output:

```
{"last_name":"Test4","first_name":"Test4","dob":"1984-09-13","unique_id":"Test4Test41984-09-13","doctor_id":19}
```

Ultimately, what I would like to do is have it display each of the object's items as a `<strong>` tag, then display the relative information. So, in simple html, the above properties would look like:

```
<strong>last_name:</strong> Test4<br>
<strong>first_name:</strong> Test4<br>
<strong>dob:</strong> 1984-09-13<br>
<strong>unique_id:</strong>Test4Test41984-09-13<br>
<strong>doctor_id:</strong> 19
```

Since the keys are different in each properties depending on what controller it was pulled from, I'm not sure how to display this. I even am having trouble finding out how to reference inside of the object. For example, `{{$key->properties->last_name}}` does not reference the last name. Neither does `{{$key->properties()->last_name}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use json_encode to store the object inside **$log->properties** you are converting the object into a json string, that's because you can't use **$key->properties->last_name**, for this you can use json_decode in your **$key->properties** variable, then you will can access each property.

To display the data regardless of variable names you can do something like this:

```
$properties = json_decode($key->properties, true);

foreach ($properties as $key => $value) {
    echo '<strong>'.$key.':</strong> '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

Or you can use blade to display this, the poin is that you need to convert your json to an array, then iterate over his keys and values.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried to work with json_decode before, but was getting all kinds of htmlspecialchars errors.